# jQuery Hidden/Show Issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have a issue where I am displaying a car and I want the user to be able to change the color of the car as well as the rims.

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
            function showImage(image){
              var mainImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
              mainImage.src = image; 
            }
            function toggleThumbnails(){
              var thumbnails = document.getElementById('color-options');
              if(thumbnails.style.display == 'block'){
                thumbnails.style.display = 'none'; 
              } else {
                thumbnails.style.display = 'block'; 
              }
            }

                function showImage(image){
              var mainImage = document.getElementById('mainwheelImage');
              mainImage.src = image; 
            }
            function toggleThumbnails(){
              var thumbnails = document.getElementById('wheel-options');
              if(thumbnails.style.display == 'block'){
                thumbnails.style.display = 'none'; 
              } else {
                thumbnails.style.display = 'block'; 
              }
            }
        </script>

<section id="footer-wrapper">
                <!-- Color Selector -->
                <div id="color-options">
                    <h1>Colors</h1>
                    <div class="color-container">
                        <div class="color-center">
                            <span><img src="img/colors/black.png" onclick="showImage('img/colors/cars/black.png')" /></span>
                            <span><img src="img/colors/white.png" onclick="showImage('img/colors/cars/white.png')" /></span>
                            <span><img src="img/colors/red.png" onclick="showImage('img/colors/cars/red.png')" /></span>
                            <span><img src="img/colors/silver.png" onclick="showImage('img/colors/cars/silver.png')" /></span>
                            <span><img src="img/colors/metalic_black.png" onclick="showImage('img/colors/cars/metalic_black.png')" /></span>
                            <span><img src="img/colors/metalic_grey.png" onclick="showImage('img/colors/cars/metalic_grey.png')" /></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Color Selector -->
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <!-- Wheels Selector -->
                <div id="wheel-options">
                    <h1>Wheels</h1>
                    <div class="wheel-container">
                        <div class="wheel-center">
                            <span><img src="img/wheels/17.jpg" onclick="showImage('img/wheels/cars_overlay/17.png')" /></span>
                            <span><img src="img/wheels/18.jpg" onclick="showImage('img/wheels/cars_overlay/18_regular.png')"  /></span>
                            <span><img src="img/wheels/18_twin.jpg" onclick="showImage('img/wheels/cars_overlay/18_twin.png')" /></span>
                            <span><img src="img/wheels/18_twin_7spoke.jpg" /></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Wheels Selector -->
```

So that toggles the colors of the car as well as the rims. But if I choose a color then when I go to select a rim, the color defaults back to the original image. Is there any way to keep the color selected while selecting the rims?

Comment: You're declaring `showImage` and `toggleThumbnails` functions twice. Try giving them different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same function name twice for different functions, and confusing the browser. Try changing the function names to something like:

```
function changeColor()
function toggleColorThumbnails()
```

and

```
function changeRim()
function toggleRimThumbnails()
```